# memory leak in mysqlcppconn program

Tags: c++, mysql

I have a program that runs that takes an increasing amount of memory. This continues until the whole program crashes. I have narrowed it down to this section--if I comment it out, the memory being used doesn't increase anymore.

Why is this section of code giving me a memory leak? Is the pointer not being deleted for some reason? Am I using the wrong `executeUpdate` function?

```
#include <cppconn/prepared_statement.h> // preparedStatement
sql::PreparedStatement* pstatement; 
try{
for(const auto& bar : m_bars) {

    std::string sql = "INSERT INTO " 
                    + m_table_name 
                    + " VALUES (' "
                    + trade_platform::datetime::toString(datetime) + "', '"
                    + bar.first + "', "
                    + "'IB', "
                    + std::to_string(bar.second.getOpen()) + ", "
                    + std::to_string(bar.second.getHigh()) + ", "
                    + std::to_string(bar.second.getLow())  + ", "
                    + std::to_string(bar.second.getClose()) + ", "
                    + std::to_string(bar.second.getVolume()) + ");";

    pstatement = m_conn->prepareStatement(sql);
    // prepare our statement and execute query
    pstatement->executeUpdate();
}
}catch(const std::exception& e){
    std::cerr << "flushToDB problem: " << e.what() << "\n"; 
}catch(...){
    std::cerr << "unspecified flushToDB problem\n";
}

// free
delete pstatement;
```

Comment: Just in case you weren't aware, you're currently not using prepared statements, your code is still vulnurable to SQL injections.

Comment: @FMashiro yes, thanks, I became aware of this distinction last night. Fortunately, this app is being run on a private server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are creating the sql statement `N` times, but only the last one gets deleted.

Deleting each statement would be better:

```
#include <memory>
...

try{
for(const auto& bar : m_bars) {

    std::string sql = "INSERT INTO " 
                    + m_table_name 
                    + " VALUES (' "
                    + trade_platform::datetime::toString(datetime) + "', '"
                    + bar.first + "', "
                    + "'IB', "
                    + std::to_string(bar.second.getOpen()) + ", "
                    + std::to_string(bar.second.getHigh()) + ", "
                    + std::to_string(bar.second.getLow())  + ", "
                    + std::to_string(bar.second.getClose()) + ", "
                    + std::to_string(bar.second.getVolume()) + ");";

    std::unique_ptr<sql::PreparedStatement> pstatement(m_conn->prepareStatement(sql)); // enabling RAII
    // prepare our statement and execute query
    pstatement->executeUpdate();

    // unique_ptr wil automatically call delete on sql statement
    // after pstatement leaves the scope, and c++ guarantees that 
    // the destructor of pstatement will be called always even in case of exception thrown
}
}catch(const std::exception& e){
    std::cerr << "flushToDB problem: " << e.what() << "\n"; 
}catch(...){
    std::cerr << "unspecified flushToDB problem\n";
}
```

Comment: This is it, if you look at the docs (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-cpp/1.1/en/connector-cpp-examples-complete-example-2.html) they delete the pointer and assign a new one after the statement changes. Note that they don't delete it if you use actual prepared statements, in which case they just execute it with different values

Comment: Better to use `RAII` to handle the `delete` then to have to manage every single case an exception may be thrown.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, that's absolutely correct, I've updated my answer employing the RAII

Comment: @Renat thanks! btw the assignment operator doesn't work for me like that, so I ended up using the constructor i.e. `std::unique_ptr<sql::PreparedStatement> p_pstmnt(m_conn->prepareStatement(sql));`

Comment: @Taylor, sorry, I haven't checked my update with compiler. Updated the answer another time

Comment: btw the check for `nullptr` in your earlier revision was redundant. `delete nullptr` does nothing (safely). What _wasn't_ safe is that the pointer was not null-initialised on declaration